# GPU for loops: avoid warp divergence & implicit syncthreads

Tags: c++, c, cuda, gpu, gpgpu

My situation:  each thread in a warp operates on its own completely independent & distinct data array.  All threads loop over their data array.  The number of loop iterations is different for each thread. (This incurs a cost, I know).

Within the for loop, each thread needs to save the maximum value after calculating three floats.  After the for-loop, threads in  warp will "communicate" by checking the maximum value calculated by only their "neighboring thread" in the *warp* (determined by parity).

**Questions:**

1. If I avoid the conditionals in a "max" operation by doing multiplication, this will avoid warp divergence, right?  (see example code below)
2. The extra multiplication operations mentioned in (1.) are worth it, right? - i.e. far faster than any sort of warp divergence.
3. The same mechanism that causes warp divergence (one set of instructions for all threads) can be exploited as an implicit "thread barrier" (for the *warp*) at the end of the for-loop  (much the same way as with an "#pragma omp for" statement in non-gpu computing).  Thus I don't need to make a "syncthreads" call for a *warp* after the for loop before one thread checks the value saved by another thread, right?  (This would be because "synthreads" is only for the "entire GPU", i.e. inter-warp and inter-MP, right?)

example code:

```
__shared__ int N_per_data;  // loaded from host
__shared__ float ** data;  //loaded from host
data = new float*[num_threads_in_warp];
for (int j = 0; j < num_threads_in_warp; ++j)
     data[j] = new float[N_per_data[j]];

// the values of jagged matrix "data" are loaded from host.


__shared__  float **max_data = new float*[num_threads_in_warp];
for (int j = 0; j < num_threads_in_warp; ++j)
     max_data[j] = new float[N_per_data[j]];

for (uint j = 0; j <  N_per_data[threadIdx.x]; ++j)
{
   const float a = f(data[threadIdx.x][j]);
   const float b = g(data[threadIdx.x][j]);
   const float c = h(data[threadIdx.x][j]);

  const int cond_a = (a > b)  &&  (a > c);
  const int cond_b = (b > a)  && (b > c);
  const int cond_c = (c > a)  && (c > b);

  // avoid if-statements.  question (1) and (2)
  max_data[threadIdx.x][j] =   conda_a * a  +  cond_b * b  +  cond_c * c; 
}



 // Question (3):
// No "syncthreads"  necessary in next line:

// access data of your mate at some magic positions (assume it exists):
float my_neighbors_max_at_7 = max_data[threadIdx.x + pow(-1,(threadIdx.x % 2) == 1) ][7];
```

Before implementing my algorithm on a GPU, I am investigating every aspect of the algorithm to ensure that it will be worth the implementation effort.  So please bear with me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes
2. My guess would be NO - depends on how you would write the other version with the ifs.
   The compiler will probably use predicates to mask out the unwanted writes, in which case there would be no real thread divergence, just a few executed but masked out write instructions.
   You should let the compiler do it's magic and compare the decompiled code for both versions to determine what is the better solution.
   In your particular case of calculating a maximum of signed integer d = a > b ? a : b translates to one PTX ISA instruction max.s32 so there is really no need to make it as complicated as you did... just compute the maximum into a temporary variable and do one unconditional write.
3. Yes, but the synthreads barrier is an intra-block barrier, not inter-block and certainly not inter-mp.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your answer to 2).  I am trying to get the maximum *float* value.  So you are saying that "max.f32" is a function which can be computed in parallel, i.e. does *not* incur a warp divergence penalty?

Comment: @MatthewParks yeah sorry, somehow i mixed that that up. For floats the instruction is max{.ftz}.f32.

Comment: @MatthewParks i am not sure what you are asking here: "So you are saying that "max.f32" is a function which can be computed in parallel, i.e. does not incur a warp divergence penalty?". Are you talking about the divergence because of the different array lengths? That would have nothing to do with the max value calculation. Or are you asking about divergence if you would do something like `if (a > b && a > c) max_data[threadIdx.x][j] = a;` ?

Comment: I am not talking about the difference in array lengths - that is a separate issue that I understand.  I am indeed asking about the divergence of the "if" statement.

Comment: So basically, the architecture can do "max" and "min" evaluations in one step (i.e. no conditionals, no divergence) by using something called "predicates", thus there is no divergence penalty.

Comment: OK.  I don't know how to interpret the compiled output, though  :)  (I am not a computer scientist).

Comment: @MatthewParks that is correct. When i compile this code `output[0] = max(a, max(b, c));` that compiles to something like this PTX:

`max.f32  %f4, %f2, %f3;
max.f32  %f5, %f1, %f4;
st.global.f32  [%r2], %f5;`

and that compiles to something like this SASS

`FMNMX R1, R2, R1, !PT;
FMNMX R1, R3, R1, !PT;
ST [R0], R1;`

No branches and no predicates :)